# Symfony 2 pdo exception

Tags: symfony, pdo, doctrine-orm

I'm using Symfony 2 and have this row in my parameters.ini:

> database_driver   = pdo_pgsql

When I was creating database structure with Doctrine everything was good. But if I want to add some doctrine object to my darabase (insert row), I catch an exception:

[image]

What I have to do with this?

Comment: Did you define it in all `php.ini` file? Because using command line, it will use the `php.ini` from cli folder, not from apache2 folder.

Comment: if you type `php -m | grep pdo` in your terminal what do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you're using **pdo_pgsql**? Are you running on localhost? It might be very certain that you are using **pdo_mysql** driver instead.

However you have to check the following:

**php.ini**

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

or in your case

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_pgsql.so
```

You can check the **phpinfo();** to find out the configured database driver.

In your symfony project you have to check the **parameters.ini** file in config folder. E.g.

```
[parameters]
    database_driver="pdo_mysql"
    database_host="localhost"
```

Besides try to avoid this error

```
'stty' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/4974

Answer (score 0):

First of all, verify your **php.ini** file: the extensions *php_pdo_pgsql* and *php_pdo* must be enabled. Make sure you apply this changes on php.ini file that your **symfony project** is using, check this on *localhost/path_to_your_project/web/config.php*. You know if this extensions are enabled executing the function phpinfo().

This command is also helpfull: php -m. It lists on console all the php modules that are loaded.

Tip: check out you **Apache error log**, there could be something wrong with the load of your extensions. This file is located according to your server configuration.